# Simplifying a trigonometric expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm sure this has been addressed before, but I can't find it!

I want *Mathematica* to simplify

```
Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2]
```

to

```
Cos[π/6 - θ]
```

Just as

```
PowerExpand[FullSimplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[θ]^2]]]
```

Does what you would expect.

Maybe the polite question would be how to transform

```
Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2]
```

to

```
Sqrt[Cos[π/6 - θ]^2]
```

Comment: This is not possible because the two expression are not equivalent: `Plot[{Sqrt[1 - Sin[\[Pi]/6 - \[Theta]]^2], Cos[\[Pi]/6 - \[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 3 Pi}]`

Comment: @halirutan: `PolarPlot[{Sqrt[Cos[\[Pi]/6 - \[Theta]]^2], Sqrt[
  1 - Sin[\[Pi]/6 - \[Theta]]^2]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`. I think you are looking at only +ive result from square root solution.Both have same polar plot.

Comment: @Blackbird I have indeed only looked at the (real) plot because usually most questions don't assume complex numbers. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Perhaps a better question is why does `Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[u]^2], Element[u, Reals]] /. u -> π/6 - θ` simplify and `Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2], Element[θ, Reals]]` does not?  *Mathematica* might apply more identities to the second, but it rejects all of them and returns the original expression.  Why does the argument make this sort of difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2] /. {Sin[x_]^2 -> 1 - Cos[x]^2} // PowerExpand
(*Cos[π/6 - θ]*)

Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2] /.{1 - Sin[x_]^2 -> Cos[x]^2},
 Element[θ, Reals]]
(*Abs[Cos[π/6 - θ]]*)

Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2] /. Sin[x_] -> Sin@ArcCos@Cos[x]
(*Sqrt[Cos[π/6 - θ]^2]*)
```

Comment: This is OK but ineloquent.

Answer (score 6):

First, it's important to realize `Sqrt[x^2]` will not simplify to `Abs[x]` unless you specify an assumption that (implies) `x` is real.  But this is interesting:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[u]^2], Element[u, Reals]] /. u -> π/6 - θ
(* Abs[Cos[π/6 - θ]] *)

Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2], Element[θ, Reals]]
(* Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2] *)
```

I don't know why the second one doesn't work (even if the assumption is `Element[π/6 - θ, Reals]`).

Here's another **workaround**:

```
pythag[e_] := e /. Sin[u_]^2 :> 1 - Cos[u]^2;
Simplify[Sqrt[ 1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2], Element[θ, Reals],
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, pythag}]
(* Abs[Cos[π/6 - θ]] *)
```

But clearly, *Mathematica* knows a transformation equivalent to `pythag`.  In fact if we substitute the grade-school approximation for `π` (or *most* other *exact* numbers), the simplification goes through:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2] /. π -> 22/7, Element[θ, Reals]]
(* Abs[Cos[11/21 - θ]] *)
```

An odd exception is the substitution `π -> GoldenRatio`.

I do not understand why there are these differences.  `Simplify` tends to minimize `LeafCount`, but it's not the only factor.  Another is the number of "digits of integers", but it still does not seem to be the complete picture. (See [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html).)  It is hard to imagine how the digits could account for the differences in these cases.  Consider the leaf counts:

```
LeafCount[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2]]
LeafCount[Sqrt[Cos[π/6 - θ]^2]]
LeafCount[Abs[Cos[π/6 - θ]]]
(* 20 *)
(* 16 *)
(* 11 *)
```

The workaround above suggests that the transformation of `1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2` to `Cos[π/6 - θ]^2` is not tried.  One surmises this is true from this:

```
foo[e_] := (Print[e]; e);
Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2], Element[θ, Reals], 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, foo}]
```

The output is somewhat long, but `Cos[π/6 - θ]^2` does not appear.  On the other hand, in the output of

```
Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[(22/7)/6 - θ]^2], Element[θ, Reals], 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, foo}]
```

`Cos[11/21 - θ]^2` appears third.

Perhaps someone else will be able to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* is able to confirm your hypothesis after the fact via `Reduce` if that's any help to you:

```
Reduce[Sqrt[1 - Sin[π/6 - θ]^2] == Cos[π/6 - θ] && -π/3 < θ < 2 π/3]
(* -(π/3) < θ < (2 π)/3 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `y=π/6 - θ`

```
r = Sqrt[1 - Sin[y]^2]
FullSimplify[r] (*Sqrt[Cos[y]^2]*)
PowerExpand[%]   (*Cos[y]*)
% /. y -> π/6 - θ
```

which gives `Cos[π/6 - θ]`

This is same like replacing a long repeated expression.

**Reason:** I am trying to specify the reason Mathematica doesn't automatically convert some forms into simpler forms.Since Mathematica doesn't support type of variable before assigning any value to it, it considers symbolic manipulations to be having complex quantity.So, all those symbolic manipulations that are not valid for both `Real` and `Complex` are not converted automatically.

`Sqrt[Exp^2]` is not resolved automatically to `Exp` because if Exp=-1, than it shall resolve to Exp=1 for the result of `Sqrt`though we were expecting -1 on canceling Sqrt against `Square`.

I think having forced Simplification using `PowerExpand` instructs `M`to consider `Real` domain.